# SwiftUI mysterious space on top of the VStack

Tags: swiftui

I have this code

```
    NavigationView{
      VStack{
        GeometryReader{ geometry in
            VStack{
                Text("a")
            }
            .frame(width:geometry.size.width)
            .background(Color.orange)
            Spacer()
        }
      }
      .modifier(NavBarModifier(font: self.fontUI,text: "Profile"))
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

I want the
GeometryReader to appear at top of the VStack, however what I get is:[image]

Where the blue line is the top of the VStack and orange is the GeometryReader. I tried adding Spacer() after the GeometryReader, but it didn't work. How can I remove that spacing?

```
struct NavBarModifier: ViewModifier{
    var font: UIFont
    var text: String
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content
        .zIndex(0)
        .animation(.spring())
        .padding(.top,80)
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(self.text),displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(false)
        .foregroundColor(.orange)
        .background(NavigationConfigurator { nc in
                       nc.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 243/255, green: 107/255, blue: 21/255, alpha: 1)
                       nc.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
                        .foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
                        .font : self.font,
                        .kern: 1.2
                       ]
        }
        .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing]))
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume it is header of NavigationView. Would you show complete code of view?

Comment: @Asperi I added the NavView and modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove redundant padding in `NavBarModifier`

```
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    return content
    .zIndex(0)
    .animation(.spring())
//    .padding(.top,80)        // << this one !!
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Spacer after the GeometryReader for it to layout in the top of the `VStack` and also add `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` for it to ignore that white space (the safe area) and make it align at the top of the `VStack`.

```swift
VStack {
    GeometryReader{ geometry in
        VStack {
            Text("s")
        }
        .frame(width:geometry.size.width)
        .background(Color.orange)

        Spacer()
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

    Spacer()
}
```